# I am trying to fill a triangle

Tags: java, geometry, shapes, fill

I am trying to fill a triangle. I tried to do it myself using

```
g.fillPolygon(Triangle.x1, Triangle.x2, Triangle.x3, Triangle.y1, 
         Triangle.y2, Triangle.y3);
```

but I am getting some errors. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class Vehicle extends JFrame

 {
    final int WIDTH = 900; int HEIGHT = 650;



public Vehicle()
    {
        //the following code creates the JFrame
        super("Radical Racing");
        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{

    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);


    int x1, y1 ,x2, y2, x3,y3;
    x1 = x2 = x3 = 200;
    y1 = y2 = y3 = 390;

    {
          triangle (g, x1=174, y1, x2=204, y2, x3=189, y3=360);

    }
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    g.fillPolygon(Triangle.x1, Triangle.x2, Triangle.x3, Triangle.y1, Triangle.y2, Triangle.y3);
    triangle(g,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);
}

void triangle(Graphics g,int x1,int y1,
        int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3){
      g.drawLine (x1, y1, x2, y2);
      g.drawLine (x2, y2, x3, y3);
      g.drawLine (x3, y3, x1, y1);
}



public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Vehicle();
    }

}
```

Comment: You should probably add Java as a tag to this so people know what language you are using.  This would help direct people to your question who are more likely to be able to help.

Answer (score 2):

You're welcome and I suggest to use oracle java api sometimes. It's really developers friendly. :)

You don't have any Triangle class with static x1... fields so why Triangle.x1...? :) And why own block to invoke triangle()?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.applet.*;
public class Vehicle extends JFrame {

    final int WIDTH = 900;
          int HEIGHT = 650;

    public Vehicle() {
        // the following code creates the JFrame
        super("Radical Racing");
        setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);

    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3;
        x1 = x2 = x3 = 200;
        y1 = y2 = y3 = 390;
        triangle(g, x1 = 174, y1, x2 = 204, y2, x3 = 189, y3 = 360);

        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillPolygon(new int[] {x1, x2, x3}, new int[] {y1, y2, y3}, 3);
        triangle(g, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
    }

    void triangle(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) {
        g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
        g.drawLine(x2, y2, x3, y3);
        g.drawLine(x3, y3, x1, y1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Vehicle();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

nvrfrgt answer works and fixes any bugs you have (gave him a +1) but there are some other things you could clean up that are worth keeping in mind (and were too long for a comment).

First off, I think you meant for `HEIGHT` to be final? Otherwise make it lowercase.

A performance thing that might make a difference later if you are drawing a bunch of racing triangles or something - you are drawing the same triangle twice (never change your x and y values), so one of these is wasted.

```
triangle (g, x1=174, y1, x2=204, y2, x3=189, y3=360);
...
triangle(g, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

How you initialized your x and y values isn't the cleanest either. You set them all to specific numbers, and then turn around and change them in the next line. Why have the initial values? The snippet below makes more sense to me anyway (though that still seems a bit too [magic numbery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants))

```
int x1 = 174; int x2 = 204; int x3 = 189;
int y1 = 390; int y2 = 390; int y3 = 360;
triangle(g, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

If you are going to draw the triangle and fill it in the same color, then drawing the lines might be unnecessary for you (makes 1pixel difference?). If that's the case, you can remove the triangle() call, or replace your triangle implementation with the fill polygon. In the end, something like this is a bit more sleek (still can work on it though):

```
public class Vehicle extends JFrame {

  final int WIDTH = 900;
  final int HEIGHT = 650; // Made this final

  public Vehicle() {
      // the following code creates the JFrame
      super("Radical Racing");
      setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    int x1 = 174; int x2 = 204; int x3 = 189;
    int y1 = 390; int y2 = 390; int y3 = 360;
    g.setColor(Color.green);
    // Got rid of redundant drawing
    triangle(g, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
  }

  void triangle(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int x3, int y3) {
    // Left both the lines and the fill so you could play with color or something.
    g.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    g.drawLine(x2, y2, x3, y3);
    g.drawLine(x3, y3, x1, y1);
    g.fillPolygon(new int[] {x1, x2, x3}, new int[] {y1, y2, y3}, 3);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Want to save this as something so you can move it around later
    Vehicle greenTriangle = new Vehicle();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

first set color:

```
g.setColor(R, G, B);
```

Then fill it:

```
g.fillTriangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```